# How to create images programatically like stack exchange image based flair

Tags: image, image-processing

I am looking to build little image up not unlike the the image based flair stack exchange now uses. I am not sure where to begin when it comes to building images programatically.

Comment: 1. You'd better use cache (to make server load less). 2. Just use something like `libpng` to save image. If you wanna create image with help of some library, try `libgd` for example. Another simpler way is to create image in SVG: you'd even not need any library!

Comment: Might detail what language or type of application you are trying to do this in -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have come accross is to use [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture), build the desired thing with css and html then save it with phantomjs.